# White Box Appearing in Chrome on Windows 7

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, windows-7

I'm working on a website for a client, and they keep telling me that when looked at in Chrome on Windows 7, certain pages have a white box appearing over parts of the content when you scroll down the page. The content then only becomes visible when you try highlighting the text. (It's a gray background with white text.)

I don't personally have Windows 7, so I can't test this, but every browser simulator I've run doesn't show a problem. I have heard from others that they can verify that this is happening, so it's not just the client.

Here's the link: http://abetterchicago.org/. Specifically, the problem appears on pages in the "About Us" and "Our Model" sections, such as http://abetterchicago.org/about-us/our-team/.

I've gone through the CSS and template files and everything is clean and written properly. If you look at the source code there's nothing out of the ordinary that I can see. No scripts other than plugins are being used.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to set the property 'overflow:auto' in your #content div pleas

Comment: While it's not directly an answer to your question, I thought I'd mention you can download free legitimate testing virtual machines directly from Microsoft [here](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads). I would recommend [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) as a free alternative to VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ul to overflow: hidden; on the advisory council .